# How to replace a character with another even if the character does not match exactly in R?

Tags: r, replace

I have a data frame like this

```
Subject     Stimulation     GATA3
A             NO stim       GATA3 149
B             1100-2        GATA3 1
C             BSV18         GATA3 100
```

I would like to do two things:

1. Replace anything that has GATA3 in it into 1 and
2. Keep the GATA3 as it is in the column name, that is, the column names should be "Subject", "Stimulation" and "GATA3".

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: Based on the example, do you need 1 for all the rows of 'GATA3' i.e. `i1 <- grep("GATA3", df1$GATA3); df1$GATA3[i1] <- 1`

Comment: Subject     Stimulation     GATA3
A             NO stim          1
B             1100-2        1 
C             BSV18         1
This is the expected output

Comment: Try `stringr::str_replace_all(df$GATA3, "GAT. *", "1")`.Not tested.

Comment: Thanks. grep worked better for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use grepl combined with as.integer for this:

```
# Building a data frame
Subject = c('A', 'B', 'C')
Stimulation = c('NO stim', 1100-2, 'BSV18')
GATA3 = c('GATA3 149', 'GATA3 1', 'GATA3 100')
df = data.frame(Subject, Stimulation, GATA3)

# Converting using grepl and as.integer 
df$GATA3 = as.integer(grepl(pattern = 'GATA3', x = df$GATA3))

# Checking results
head(df)
```

Comment: This would change any element that does not contain "GATA3" to 0, wouldn't it? You may use `df$GATA3[grepl(pattern = 'GATA3', x = df$GATA3)] <- 1`

Comment: Thanks @markus. Yes, this would replace the non-matches with 0's. One advantage of this is that after transformation, numerical operations could be performed on the column (sum, etc.). However, if there is no need for numerical analysis, your solution is a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `grep` to create a index where the 'GATA3' elements are present in the 'GATA3' and assign based on that index

```
i1 <- grep("GATA3", df1$GATA3)
df1$GATA3[i1] <- 1
```

NOTE: The OP wanted to replace only specific rows of the column and not the entire column